# PyQt4, Centos7 and Python3- ImportError: No module named 'PyQt4'

Tags: python, linux, pyqt4, redhat, centos7

I'm working on Centos7 and using Python 3.3.2.
I'm trying to run a Python script that uses PyQt4 modules but I'm getting this error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt4'
```

The script doesn't yet have it's full functionality but I'm just trying to ensure it runs and can access the correct modules etc at this early stage as I'm new to python. Here is the script so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from os.path import expanduser
import os
import shlex

#import Converted Python UI File
from mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow
class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
# Connect the Buttons
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.selectFileButton,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.selectFile)
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.convertButton,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.convert)


def selectFile(self):
        fileName = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,'Open Media File',expanduser("~"),'Media Files (*.mov *.avi *.mkv *.mpg)')
        self.ui.fileName.setText(fileName)

def convert(self):
        self.convertFile()



def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
#if __name__ == “__main__”:
    main()
```

I definitely have PyQt installed.

When I run:

```
rpm -ql PyQt4
```

It produces something like this:

```
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/Qt.so
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtCore.so
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtDBus.so
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtDeclarative.so
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtDesigner.so
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtGui.so
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtHelp.so
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtMultimedia.so
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtNetwork.so
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtOpenGL.so
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtScript.so
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtScriptTools.so
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtSql.so
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtSvg.so
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtTest.so
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtXml.so
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtXmlPatterns.so
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/__init__.py
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/__init__.pyc
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/__init__.pyo
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/phonon.so
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/pyqtconfig.py
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/pyqtconfig.pyc
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/pyqtconfig.pyo
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/uic
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/uic/Compiler
```

Which suggests PyQt is installed to work with Python2. How can I correct this so that it works with Python 3.3.2?
I've tried `yum install python-pyqt4`  but on Centos there doesn't seem to be a package available. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: please show your code

Comment: this has now been added.

Comment: you can't "correct" this, you need to install PyQt5 with Python3 support

Comment: @Qchmqs - the tutorial I'm following uses PyQt4 with Python3. is there a specific reason why I can't do the same? Is it related to the version of Linux I'm using?

Comment: py3 and py2 are different beasts, find where's the pyqt4 for py3 package for your OS, there is no problem to fix, the library you need isn't installed, you installed a different version

Comment: try with: yum install python3-pyqt4

Comment: @eyllanesc as I say, I have tried `yum install python3-pyqt4` and I get `No package python3-pyqt4 available.` on Centos7

Comment: try with: yum install python3-PyQt4 https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=python3-PyQt4

Comment: I've resolved the issue it by re-installing PyQt4 using these instructions `http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/installation.html` , but I specified python3 during the `python configure-ng.py` part, so I used  `python3 configure-ng.py` instead and it seems to have worked.